# Where is this hose supposed to connect in my clothes washer?

Tags: washer

I had a hose come loose on my Samsung front load washer model # WF395BTPASU/A1

It is a small black hose, about 2.5 feet long, that runs from the top of the drain pump in the front of the washer along the left side to the back of the drum.

The water spews out during the rinse and spin cycle. Where the hose connects is on the top of the drain pump and was found laying along the left side frame almost touching the back frame wall. Does anyone know where the other end of the hose connects?

[image]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

[image]

Comment: Pictures will help.  Most hoses are usually placed on round nipples(small pipes/tubes) or in a hole for a tank.

Comment: Look for an exploded diagram of your washer model, either from the manufacturer or from an appliance parts site. Also check for a bit of hose, rather than a place to connect a hose to, in case it broke, rather than coming loose.

Comment: The hose is not broken or cracked. The clamp worked loose and is still on the end. I will try to add pictures

Comment: A clamp should mean a nipple somewhere.  Would check the end of the hose to see if a broken off nipple is inside.

Comment: It probably connects to the drain outlet.

Comment: Added the images from the deleted non-answer posts the OP attempted to put them in.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is this hose that attaches somewhere around the 10-o'clock position on the front of the drum:

[image]

If so it attaches to the part labelled 7-7-3 in this diagram:
[image]

That part, however, is discontinued and it has no name or product page on Samsung's web site.  Hopefully that part is still intact and you can find it and connect to it.

Reference: https://samsungparts.com/pages/exploded-views-assembly?mfg=SMG&ariId=32417&assemblyId=32410.  Not your exact model but from the same line.